# Need Related Products in bottom of product detailed page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, related-products

I need to display related products below the description(bottom of the page) but in theme it is coming right side of the page(we are using Porto theme).
Could anyone please tell me how to display related products bottom of the page ?

For reference please find the attached image.

[image]
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you resolved your query?

Comment: Yes problem has been solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using other theme or your custom theme, you could customize the `related products position` by layout file.

In the directory `app\design\frontend\Vendor\Your_theme_name\Magento_Catalog\layout\`, create the file `catalog_product_view.xml`, in it write the codes like below, then related products will show in bottom part of product view page.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="block-name-where-you-want-to-place-it" />
    </body>
</page>
```

In the `<move>`, you could add `after | before` attribute to assign the element's position relative to siblings. If the attribute is omitted, the element is placed after all siblings.

**I hope this will help**

Comment: I think this will help.